# Get the 'next' resource with REST API, after an update

Tags: rest, api

I'm building a client-side flow where the user updates a resource in some way and then moves to the 'next' resource to update. To complicate matters the collection of resources that the user needs to traverse are picked by some criteria - filters - that the user gets to specify once, before starting the flow.

It would be ideal to not get the entire collection to traverse at the beginning as that's 'problematically stateful'. This is because the resources change states often and that a change of state affects what the 'next' resource is. Caching the collection at the beginning may produce far too many 'wrong nexts' in the client-side cached collection, as the user traverses it.

How would you design this API to minimise its chattyness? Is there a design in which within a single update, filters are piggybacked onto the request (probably as query params) and the filter-based 'next' resource is bundled into the response (perhaps in some 'meta' structure), that maintains REST semantics? If not, what other scheme should I opt for?

Comment: What kind of changes in the state are you expecting? Are they just appends to the collection, or complete reshuffles?

Comment: I'm expecting members of the collection to actually be removed as they've been already updated in some way and thus should not be shown in the flow.

Comment: How do you want the client to behave in those situations? Given that some entries have disappeared from previous pages, do you just want it to get the next state, ignoring deleted entries from cached pages?